# Best way to store preferred theme?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I created a "change theme" function for my website. All is well until after a few days when I am visiting the site, it is serving me the default theme. It needs to be reloaded before the theme takes effect.

I am storing a variable in cookies for the chosen theme then check it every time I load the site to determine what stylesheet I am going to load.

Example: 
If a user chooses "dark theme"

```
document.cookie = "theme=dark; expires=Tue, 18 Dec 2018 12:00:00 UTC"
```

and if a user chooses "light theme"

```
document.cookie = "theme=light; expires=Tue, 18 Dec 2018 12:00:00 UTC"
```

I want to know if there is a downside to this, and if there are any better ways to store the preferred theme variable other than cookies?

I suspect that the reason why this is happening is that the PHP conditional statement that I have is being rendered before the browser interprets the cookies. I may be wrong about this, if so, please let me know.

Here is the catch: There are no errors from the server side and from the client side (PHP and JavaScript.)

**EDIT:** 

The problem is that, it is serving the default "light theme" even though the cookies stored have the "dark theme". It requires a refresh of the page for the dark theme to show up. There are no errors.

Here is the PHP validation that I am using in the header to determine the cookie variable

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['theme']) && $_COOKIE['theme'] == 'dark'){
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dark-theme.css">';
}else{
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="light-theme.css">';
}
```

Note: I am not caching anything, and there are no cached versions from the network console of the browser.

Comment: is there something missing form the question? it does not currently make sense "I suspect that the reason why this is happening" you dont say what is happening

Comment: Show the code you are using to determine which theme to use, ie the conditional statement and the statements that actually output the theme.

Comment: *It requires a refresh of the page for the dark theme to show up.* You mean if you open your browser afresh it shows default but after 2nd refresh it works fine and shows dark?

Comment: Yes @Viney that is exactly what is happening 

EDIT: And there are no errors on PHP and on JavaScript. This happened 3 or 4 times on the day that I posted my question. As of today July 1, it's not happening yet, but I am afraid that it might happen to my users.